# How to combine two UIImages into a single Image in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimage

I've been trying to merge two images where one is on top and the other at the bottom. This code below doesn't seem to work. The x coordinator is correct but the y doesn't seem right and it crops the top image when I alter it. What am I doing wrong?

```
func combine(bottomImage: Data, topImage: Data) -> UIImage {
    let bottomImage = UIImage(data: topImage)
    let topImage = UIImage(data: bottomImage)
    let size = CGSize(width: bottomImage!.size.width, height: bottomImage!.size.height + topImage!.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let areaSizeb = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bottomImage!.size.width, height: bottomImage!.size.height)
    let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: topImage!.size.width, height: topImage!.size.height)
    bottomImage!.draw(in: areaSizeb)
    topImage!.draw(in: areaSize)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be SwiftUI -- do you mean UIKit?

Comment: Where is the SwiftUI in this question?

Comment: "the y doesn't seem right" It isn't. The bottom image y needs to be the top image height. Also these are not sizes, they are rects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing both images into the same rect. You also should not use force-unwrapping. That causes your app to crash if anything goes wrong.

There are also various other small mistakes.

Change your function like this:

```
// Return an Optional so we can return nil if something goes wrong
func combine(bottomImage: Data, topImage: Data) -> UIImage? {

    // Use a guard statement to make sure 
    // the data can be converted to images
    guard 
      let bottomImage = UIImage(data: bottomImage),
      let topImage = UIImage(data: topImage) else {
        return nil
    }
    // Use a width wide enough for the widest image
    let width = max(bottomImage.size.width, topImage.size.width)

    // Make the height tall enough to stack the images on top of each other.
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: bottomImage.size.height + topImage.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let bottomRect = CGRect(
      x: 0, 
      y: 0, 
      width: bottomImage.size.width, 
      height: bottomImage.size.height)

    // Position the bottom image under the top image.
    let topRect = CGRect(
      x: 0, 
      y: bottomImage.size.height, 
      width: topImage.size.width, 
      height: topImage.size.height)
        
    bottomImage.draw(in: bottomRect)

    topImage!.draw(in: topRect)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

(And you should really be using a UIGraphicsImageRenderer rather than than calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`/ `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`.)

### Edit:

Note that if the 2 images are different widths the above code will leave a "dead space" on the right of the narrower image. You could also make the code center the narrower image, or scale it up to be the same width. (If you do scale it up I suggest scaling it up in both dimensions to preserve the original aspect ratio. Otherwise it will look stretched and unnatural.)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you should click the check-mark to accept it. That is a very strong norm on this site. Once you have enough reputation, up-voting particularly helpful answers is also good form, although optional.

Comment: And your question appears to be about pure Swift, not SwiftUI. You should edit your question to change the title and keywords to Swift, or add relevant SwiftUI code so that the question actually has a SwiftUI component to it.